# linux + ssh + perform two tasks in one ssh and print to CSV

Tags: linux, ssh, awk, sed, csv

the following command print the two values in one ssh shut

```
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd "


test01
INTERVAL=240
```

but how to change the syntax in order to print the following format: (CSV) ,

```
 test01,INTERVAL=240
```

.

I try to ( but not as expected )

```
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd " | awk '{print $1","$2}'


test01,
INTERVAL=240,
```

Comment: do you always execute two commands, the output format is always the same ?

Comment: I not want to run the ssh twice and inserting the output to variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is parse the command's output and replace the first newline (`\n`) with a comma. This should work:

```
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd " | 
    perl -00pe 's/\n/,/'
```

Here we're using `perl` to slurp the entire file into memory (`-0`) and replace the first `\n` with a comma. The `-p` tells `perl` to print each input "line" (here, a line is the entire file) after running the script given by `-e` on it.

---

The reason your `awk` didn't work is because `awk` runs the script you give it on every line. Your command prints two lines, both of which only have a single field, `$1`, so `$2` is undefined. Therefore, `print $1","$2` is expanded to `print "test01"","` for the first line and `print "INTERVAL=240"","` for the second, resulting in

```
test01,
INTERVAL=240,
```

A working solution with `awk` would be:

```
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd " | 
    awk '{printf "%s,", $1}' | sed 's/,$//'
```

That will print the 1st field of each line followed by a comma. The `sed` command just removes the trailing comma after the last line printed.

To print the whole line instead of just one field, use:

```
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd " | 
    awk '{printf "%s,", $0}' | sed 's/,$//'
```

Comment: excellent - another question  how to fit also in case we want to add more then two tasks? for example - "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd && cat /etc/redhat-release "

Comment: @yael the `awk` solution in the updated answer will work for any number of output lines.

Comment: yes I try it but its print only partial from the third task "cat /etc/redhat-release" , its print Red and not all as Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)

Comment: @yael see updated answer. However, please don't do this. Your question only mentioned 2 lines of output and you now have multiple lines and also single commands that produce multiple lines. That is quite a different situation. So, either come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) or post a new question showing the text you need to parse and the output you want to see.

Comment: Nice answer, you could add a `sed` solution along the lines of `ssh test01 "hostname && date && hostname" | sed ':a;N;s/\n/, /;ba'` which works for multiple lines too, its problematic for higher linecounts though.

Comment: @DominikGebhart you may as well post it yourself. I don't tend to use sed labels much so while I could decipher that, it's not the kind of thing I'm comfortable with. It's a cool approach though, so do consider posting it.

Comment: Thanks, i just did. It go a bit out of hand, but i found it interesting. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Following [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)'s advice, im adding an alternative approach using `sed`, i mainly include it for completeness, however unlike the `awk '{printf "%s,", $1}'` which aggregates whilst ommitting the *newline*, with `sed`we are actively replacing the *newlines*, thus it would also fit in when we wanted to replace a different character. It is **inefficient** though.

The command in question is `ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D" | sed ':a;N;s/\n/, /;ba'`

The very cryptic `sed` command `:a;N;s/\n/, /;ba` is actually quite simple if taken apart.

`sed`transforms the input in one single pass (opposed to i.e. `ed`, however `ed` usually isnt included by default).
The unmodified ssh command returns:

```
[me@hostname ~]$ ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D"
05
Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal
a
s
d
f
d
05/04/16
```

If we add `N;s/\n//` we get:

```
[me@hostname ~]$ ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D" | sed 'N;s/\n//'
05Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal
as
df
d05/04/16
```

The `N` appends the *next* input line into the pattern space, the following `s/\n//` removes the *newline* in the pattern space. Thats why we get pairs of lines with removed *newlines* here.

Now if we want the full input to get sent into the pattern space, we need to *loop* with help of a label.

```
[me@hostname ~]$ ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D" | sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ba'
05Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimalasdfd05/04/16
```

With `:a` we set a label, with `ba` we unconditionally jump to the label `a`.

So what `sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ba'`  does is:

- Define label `a`
- Append next line to pattern space (`N`)
- Send pattern space through `s/\n//`
- Jump back to `a`

Once there is no new line for `N` to append it quits to the end of the script.

To get it CS we just need to change the replacement:

```
[me@hostname ~]$ ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D" | sed ':a;N;s/\n/, /;ba'
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s, d, f, d, 05/04/16
```

This isnt very efficient, especially for bigger linecount, since the pattern space gets the line appended and sent trought our replacement command for every single line. Would be more efficient to replace before aggregation, but `sed` can't do that.

This becomes very obvious if we print the pattern space after `N` appended the next line (Just put a `p` at the position to get the current pattern space printed).
 In the following ouput, every 2 lines represetn the current pattern space (because the *newline is still included) - just before the replacement of the newline by `s/\n//`:

```
[me@hostname] ssh test01 "date +%m && hostname && cat asdfd.txt && date +%D" | sed ':a;N;p;s/\n/, /;ba'
05
Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal
a
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a
s
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s
d
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s, d
f
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s, d, f
d
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s, d, f, d
05/04/16
05, Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal, a, s, d, f, d, 05/04/16
```

Answer (score 0):

For your command this would produce the expected output :

```
counter=0
ssh test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd " \
  | while read line ; do 
  ((counter++)) 
  if [[ counter -eq 1 ]]; then 
    echo -ne "${line},"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
  done
```

Comment: excellent , but how to fit also in case we want to add more then two tasks as - ssh ub-test01 "hostname && cat  /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd && cat /etc/redhat-release " ??

Comment: in this case you change the `if [[ counter -eq 1 ]]` to `if [[ counter -eq 2 ]]`

Comment: I did it but its print that - test01,INTERVAL=240
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) ( so we have two lines in place on csv line )

Comment: corrected script to use instead of $line the quoted variable "$line", this way you'll probably have the right output

Comment: also , my previous comment is wrong, you have to correct  `if [[ counter -eq 1 ]]` to `if [[ counter -le 2 ]]`